Pytorch Lightning Multiclass 3D image classifier only predicts one class
Okay so to state first:
I have no coding / AI background, i have been learning this over the past few months, and i want to learn more!
After some time i created an image classifier with the help of pytorch lightning with the medmnist dataset, when i was confident that everything worked, i changed to another dataset.
But now it only guesses one class. I have been researching this problem and it often says data imbalance, which is an issue for me. But i thought with correct weights it should fix the problem of only guessing 1 class. But this did not work for me. I have tried to have more balanced data but still same issue.
So i have been trying a lot of solutions and checking if the optimizers work correctly, which i think they do..
Also


def main():

    import torch
    import os
    from torch import optim, utils, Tensor
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torch.utils.data as data
    from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
    from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
    from tqdm import tqdm
    import torchmetrics
    from torchmetrics.classification import MulticlassROC, MulticlassAUROC
    from lightning.pytorch.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
    import lightning as L

    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
    
    import datetime
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    month = current_datetime.month
    day = current_datetime.day
    hour = current_datetime.hour
    minute = current_datetime.minute
    todaysdate = "{:02d}-{:02d}_{:02d}:{:02d}".format(month, day, hour, minute)

    """# Model - Data Prep"""
    #                      Importing the datasets
    print(f"{todaysdate} \nImporting Perfusion dataset...   ")

    from MyFile.Tryouts.NewLoader import perfusionmaps_dataset

    ##                      Dataset:
    dataset_train = perfusionmaps_dataset(mode='train', method='sv', relative=True)
    dataset_val = perfusionmaps_dataset(mode='val', method='sv', relative=True)
    dataset_test = perfusionmaps_dataset(mode='test', method='sv', relative=True)
    
    print(f'        Trainset: {len(dataset_train)}, '
                    f'valset: {len(dataset_val)}, testset: {len(dataset_test)}')

    lr = 0.001

    ##                      Dataloader
    batch_size_final = 1
    train_loader = data.DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=batch_size_final, shuffle=True)
    val_loader = data.DataLoader(dataset_val, batch_size=batch_size_final, shuffle=False)
    test_loader = data.DataLoader(dataset_test, batch_size=batch_size_final, shuffle=False)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #                       Label names printing
    classes_labels = {
        0: "Other (m3 or anterior)",
        1: "ICA",
        2: "ICA-T",
        3: "M1",
        4: "M2",
        5: "No occlusion"
    }
    num_classes = len(classes_labels)
    classes = list(classes_labels.keys())
    label_names = list(classes_labels.values())
    print(f"        Classes with Labels:    {num_classes}\n" 
          f"        Classes numerical:      {classes} \n"
          f"        Label names:            {label_names[:3]}\n"
          f"                                    ...{label_names[3:]}\n"
          f"        Learning Rate:          {lr}\n"
          f"        Batch Size:             {batch_size_final}\n"

    print("... Done!\n")

    # CCN MODEL DEFINITION
    print(f"Model setup:")
    # Ques_print = input("        Model size diagnosis? (Yes/No)   ").lower()
    Ques_print = "No".lower()
    Q_New_or_save = input("        New training (New) or from earlier save (Save)?: ").lower()
    # Q_New_or_save = "new".lower()
    if Q_New_or_save == "new":
        # NUM_EPOCHS = int(input("        How many epochs?: "))
        NUM_EPOCHS = 5
    print(f"... Setup done")

    writer = SummaryWriter("")      

    class CNNModel(L.LightningModule):
        def __init__(self):
            super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
            # input (1, 256,256,32)
            ## Layer 1
            self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(1, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=1)
            self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
            self.pooling1 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
            # output (32, 128,128,16)

            ## Layer 2
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=1)
            self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
            self.pooling2 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
            # output (64, 64, 64, 8)

            ## Layer 3
            self.conv3 = nn.Conv3d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=1)
            self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
            self.pooling3 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
            # output (128, 32,32,4)

            ## Layer 4          -       Extra layered
            self.conv4 = nn.Conv3d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=1)
            self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
            self.pooling4 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
            # output (256, 16,16,2)

            self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
            # output (524288)       -       (131072)

            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256 *16*16*2, 1028)
            self.relu5 = nn.ReLU()
            # self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128 * 32 * 32 * 4, 512)
            # self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
            # output (512)      -    (1028)

            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1028, 256)
            self.relu5 = nn.ReLU()
            # output (256)

            # self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
            self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, num_classes)
            self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
            # output (6) Classes

            # Extra
            self.on_validation_step_outputs = []
            self.on_test_step_outputs = []

            ## Torch Lightning metrics
            # Accuracy
            self.train_acc = torchmetrics.classification.Accuracy(task='multiclass',
                                                                  num_classes=num_classes,
                                                                  average='weighted')
            self.val_acc = torchmetrics.classification.Accuracy(task='multiclass',
                                                                num_classes=num_classes,
                                                                average='none')
            self.val_W_acc = torchmetrics.classification.Accuracy(task='multiclass',
                                                                  num_classes=num_classes,
                                                                  average='weighted',
                                                                  multidim_average='global')
            self.test_acc = torchmetrics.classification.Accuracy(task='multiclass',
                                                                 num_classes=num_classes,

            # Loss functions
            self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

        def forward(self, x):
            batch_size, channels, width, height, depth = x.size()
            # print(f"batch_size:{batch_size}")
            if Ques_print == "yes":
                print(f"Before anything: {x.size()}")

            x = self.relu1(self.conv1(x))
            x = self.pooling1(x)

            if Ques_print == "yes":
                print(f"after conv1: {x.size()}")

            x = self.relu2(self.conv2(x))
            x = self.pooling2(x)

            if Ques_print == "yes":
                print(f"after conv2: {x.size()}")

            x = self.relu3(self.conv3(x))
            x = self.pooling3(x)

            if Ques_print == "yes":
                print(f"after conv3: {x.size()}")

            x = self.relu4(self.conv4(x))
            x = self.pooling4(x)

            if Ques_print == "yes":
                print(f"after conv4: {x.size()}")

            # Flattening
            x = x.view(-1, 131072)

            if Ques_print == "yes":
                print(f"after flattening: {x.size()}")

            # x = self.relu4(self.fc1(x))
            x = self.relu5(self.fc1(x))

            if Ques_print == "yes":
                print(f"after fc1: {x.size()}")

            # x = self.fc2(x)
            x = self.relu5(self.fc2(x))

            if Ques_print == "yes":
                print(f"after fc2: {x.size()}")

            x = self.fc3(x)

            if Ques_print == "yes":
                print(f"after fc3: {x.size()}")

            x = self.softmax(x)

            if Ques_print == "yes":
                print(f"after softmax: {x.size()}")

            print(f'end x: {x}')

            return x

        def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
            # Prep
            x, labels, Labels_int = batch

            labels_int = [tensor[0].item() for tensor in Labels_int]

            comp_class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                      classes=np.unique(labels_int),
                                                      y=labels_int)

            class_weights = torch.tensor(comp_class_weights,
                                         dtype=torch.float32).to(self.device)

            print(f'Class Weights: {class_weights}')

            # # Training
            x = x.float()
            x = x.view(x.size(0), 1, 256, 256, 32)
            logits = self.forward(x)

            # print(f"\nLogits: {logits}\nlabels: {labels}")

            # Loss
            criterion_weighted = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)
            loss = criterion_weighted(logits, labels)

            self.log("train/loss", loss)
            tensorboard_logs = {'train_loss': loss}

            # Track accuracy
            self.train_acc(logits, labels)
            self.log('train/acc', self.train_acc,
                     on_step=False, on_epoch=True)

            # return loss
            return {'loss': loss, 'log': tensorboard_logs}

        def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
            x_val, labels_val = batch
            x_val = x_val.float()
            logits = self.forward(x_val)

            loss_val = self.criterion(logits, labels_val)

            self.on_validation_step_outputs.append(loss_val)

            # Acc per Class
            labels_val = torch.argmax(labels_val, dim=1)
            # print(f"Problem with val_acc?: {logits.shape},{labels_val.shape}")
            self.val_acc(logits, labels_val)
            accuracy_value = self.val_acc.compute()

            # print(f"accuracy_value: {accuracy_value}")
            # print(f"accuracy_value.shape: {accuracy_value.shape}")

            for i in range(accuracy_value.shape[0]):
                self.log(f'val/acc/class_{i}', accuracy_value[i],
                         on_step=True, on_epoch=True)

            # Acc weighted mean
            # print(f"Problem with val_W_acc?: {logits.shape},{labels_val.shape}")
            self.val_W_acc(logits, labels_val)
            accuracy_W_value = self.val_W_acc.compute()
            accuracy_W_value = accuracy_W_value.item()

            self.log('val/W_acc', accuracy_W_value,
                     on_step=False, on_epoch=True)

            return loss_val, accuracy_W_value

        def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
            average_val_loss = torch.stack(self.on_validation_step_outputs).mean()
            self.log("val/loss", average_val_loss, prog_bar=True)

            tensorboard_logs = {'val/loss': average_val_loss}
            self.on_validation_step_outputs.clear()

            return {'avg_val_loss': average_val_loss, 'log': tensorboard_logs}

        def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
            x_test, labels_test = batch
            x_test = x_test.float()
            y_test = self.forward(x_test)

            print(f'\ny_test: {y_test}')
            print(f'labels_test: {labels_test}')

            # labels_test = labels_test.view(-1).long()
            # print("Before loss function")
            loss_test = self.criterion(y_test, labels_test)
            self.on_test_step_outputs.append(loss_test)

            labels_test = torch.argmax(labels_test, dim=1)
            print(f"y_test: {y_test}"
                  f"labels_test: {labels_test}")

            # print("Before accuracy function")
            accuracy_value_test = self.test_acc(y_test, labels_test)
            # accuracy_value_test = test_acc_.compute()
            for i in range(accuracy_value_test.shape[0]):
                self.log(f'test/acc/class_{i}', accuracy_value_test[i],
                         on_step=True, on_epoch=False)

            return loss_test

        def on_test_epoch_end(self):
            average_test_loss = torch.stack(self.on_test_step_outputs).mean()
            self.log("test/loss", average_test_loss, prog_bar=True)

            tensorboard_logs = {'test/loss': average_test_loss}
            self.on_test_step_outputs.clear()

            return {'avg_test_loss': average_test_loss, 'log': tensorboard_logs}

        def configure_optimizers(self):
            optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=lr)

            return optimizer

    # Initialize the CNN model
    cnn_model = CNNModel()

   # Callbacks
    ckpt_callback = ModelCheckpoint(monitor='val/W_acc', save_top_k=1, mode='max',
                                        dirpath=save_callback_path,
                                        filename=
                                        'callback_Ep{epoch}_{val/W_acc:.2f}'+f'_{todaysdate}',
                                        auto_insert_metric_name=False)
   ## Train the model
   trainer = L.Trainer(max_epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                            callbacks=ckpt_callback
                            )
   trainer.fit(model=cnn_model,
                    train_dataloaders=train_loader,
                    val_dataloaders=val_loader
                    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()



And this is the summary of the model:
  | Name      | Type               | Params
--------------------------------------------------
0  | conv1     | Conv3d             | 896   
1  | relu1     | ReLU               | 0     
2  | pooling1  | MaxPool3d          | 0     
3  | conv2     | Conv3d             | 55.4 K
4  | relu2     | ReLU               | 0     
5  | pooling2  | MaxPool3d          | 0     
6  | conv3     | Conv3d             | 221 K 
7  | relu3     | ReLU               | 0     
8  | pooling3  | MaxPool3d          | 0     
9  | conv4     | Conv3d             | 884 K 
10 | relu4     | ReLU               | 0     
11 | pooling4  | MaxPool3d          | 0     
12 | flatten   | Flatten            | 0     
13 | fc1       | Linear             | 134 M 
14 | relu5     | ReLU               | 0     
15 | fc2       | Linear             | 263 K 
16 | fc3       | Linear             | 1.5 K 
17 | softmax   | Softmax            | 0     
18 | train_acc | MulticlassAccuracy | 0     
19 | val_acc   | MulticlassAccuracy | 0     
20 | val_W_acc | MulticlassAccuracy | 0     
21 | test_acc  | MulticlassAccuracy | 0     
22 | criterion | CrossEntropyLoss   | 0     
--------------------------------------------------
136 M     Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
136 M     Total params
544.682   Total estimated model params size (MB)

Further as i said before, im learning and still want to learn so is there someone who can see the issue ':)
I have tried:
balancing the datasets
tinkering with the optimizers
etc.

Maybe it's not the problem with code but with the annotations? What data type format are you using for labels (VOC, CSV, COCO)? I had a similar problem, even for only two classes and well-balanced data (uniform distribution for dummy images with simple shapes, black and white palette and the same size). For these images I prepared COCO json annotations file and the problem was inside. It turned out that there must be additional category with "id": 0 just for background, eg. "name": "BACKGROUND" - not used but it seems needed. When I added this category, objects for all classes are clearly detected and properly classified on every images, even on new ones which are slightly difficult to detect and classify. Dataset was small (100 images) and the training run just for 15 epochs but it was enough for getting IoU metric > 95% for every object. Also, my first fault few days ago was that I generated COCO with bounding boxes in XYXY format instead of XYWH. Maybe these two things will be the clue in your case.
